# Property declaration with types with quotes or numbers

Tags: typescript

The following is valid typescript code:

```
class Greeter {
    one: 'Daniel';
    two: 123.45;
    greet() {
        return `Hello ${this.one} ${this.two}`;
    }
}
```

Note the colon instead of the equal sign on the `one` and `two` properties.

This seems to be valid code and the IDE tells me that `one` is of type `'Daniel'` and `two` is of type `123.45`.

Is there a valid use case where something like that would make sense?

Comment: The first one is a *"string literal type"*, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types. The second is a *"numeric literal type"*, see the next section down.

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer or should I?

Comment: It can make sense: `function rollDie(): 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 {
    // ...
}`

Comment: That's not the answer. The question is whether there are valid use cases, not what they are.

Comment: The answer should obviously have a bit more meat than just a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief aside: Note that your code does actually give a warning with TypeScript v2.7 and above in `--strict` mode or when setting the [`--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization).  The idea is that the two properties are neither initialized nor set in the constructor, which is likely to be an error.

---

The big use case for an interface or class with a single literal value is a [discriminated union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).  Say you have interfaces with a single-literal-typed property like

```
interface Dog {
  kind: "dog";
  bark();
}

interface Cat {
  kind: "cat";
  meow();
}

interface Fish {
  kind: "fish";
  swim();
}
```

then you can switch on that property to narrow an object whose type is an unknown member of the union of those interfaces to just one of them.  That is, you can switch on the `kind` property to narrow an object of type `Dog | Cat | Fish` to something on which you can safely call `bark()`, `meow()` or `swim()`.

---

Similarly, when you are narrowing a general class to a more specific subclass.  Like this:

```
class GreetAnybody {
   one: string = "default";
   two: number = 0;
   greet() {
       return `Hello ${this.one} ${this.two}`;
   }
}

class GreetOnlyDaniel extends GreetAnybody {
    one: 'Daniel' = 'Daniel';
    two: 123.45 = 123.45;
}
```

---

Finally, some JavaScript objects kind of need to be typed this way.  If you look at [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag), you will see that in ES2015 some built-in JavaScript objects (or objects constructed by built-in JavaScript constructors) have well-known constant string values for this property.  And therefore the [TypeScript libraries for them](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.0/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L5678) have single-value-literal properties, such as:

```
interface Math {
    readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Math";
}
```

---

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very nice explanation. Not sure why people had the need to downvote this question and my attempt at an answer. This is certainly not an obvious feature of the language.

Answer (score -1):

As per [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572036/property-declaration-with-types-with-quotes-or-numbers#comment86151570_49572036), these are "string literal types" and "numeric literal types".
Those types reduce the number of allowed values to those specified, in the case of this question:

For `one` only the value `'Daniel'` is allowed.
For `two` only the value `123.45` is allowed.

This is a special case as in this example only one value is allowed. Usually, multiple values would be allowed like so:

```
one: 'Daniel' | 'Patrick';
```

A valid use case for a property with only one valid value doesn't come to mind. In other scenarios however - e.g. method overloading - valid use cases exist with just one valid value.